# Can I edit the aggregation without getting a new approval?

Tags: facebook-timeline

I searched the documentation but didn't find anything and wanted to be sure. I didn't want us having to wait a few days for another submission to go through when we just want to make a couple of edits.

UPDATE: Just took a shot at it and you can edit aggregations, actions and objects without getting a new approval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmation: You can edit aggregations, actions and objects without getting a new approval. Tested it and wasn't required to approve again.